# Convergence of signed measures implies inequality between variations

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf, signed-measures

I'm trying to tackle Junghenn's *Principles of Real Analysis*' exercise 5.11:

> Let $\mu, \mu_1, \mu_2, \dots$ be signed measures on $(X, \mathfrak{F})$ with $\mu_n \to \mu$. Show that $\mu^{\pm}(E) \leq \liminf_{n} \mu_n^{\pm}(E)$ and $|\mu|(E) \leq \liminf_{n} |\mu_n|(E)$.

I started off trying to prove that $\mu = \liminf_{n} \mu_n^+ - \liminf_{n} \mu_n^-$ to conclude the first inequality, but this didn't seem to pay off, since I couldn't prove that $\liminf_{n} \mu_n^+$ and $\liminf_{n} \mu_n^-$ were measures. I've also tried to use the fact that
$$\mu^+(E) = \sup\{\mu(A) : A \in \mathfrak{F} \cap E\}$$
along with
$$\liminf_{n} \mu_n^+ = \sup\bigg\{ \inf\Big\{ \sup\{ \mu_k(A) : A \in \mathfrak{F} \cap E \} : k \geq n \Big\} : n \geq 1 \bigg\},$$
but I kind of got tangled up between all the supremums and infimums, and I couldn't make much progress. Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I was finally able to do it. I'll post my solution in case someone might want to take a look at it.

Comment: What is the definition of $\mu_n \to \mu$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It's setwise convergence: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu_n(A) = \mu(A)$ for all $A \in \mathfrak{F}$

Answer (score 1):

We will first show that $\mu^{\pm}(E) \leq \liminf_{n} \mu_{n}^{\pm}(E)$. Let $E \in \mathfrak{F}$. We know that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$
\mu_n^{+}(E) = \sup\{ \mu_n(A) : A \in \mathfrak{F} \cap E \}
$$
$$
\mu_n^{-}(E) = - \inf\{ \mu_n(A) : A \in \mathfrak{F} \cap E \}.
$$
Thus, it is clear that for each $A \in \mathfrak{F} \cap E$,
$$
\mu_n(A) \leq \mu_n^{+}(E) \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
$$
-\mu_n(A) \leq \mu_n^{-}(E) \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
Since $\mu_n \to \mu$, this implies that
$$
\mu(A) \leq \liminf_{n} \mu_n^{+}(E) \quad \forall A \in \mathfrak{F} \cap E
$$
$$
-\mu(A) \leq \liminf_{n} \mu_n^{-}(E) \quad \forall A \in \mathfrak{F} \cap E.
$$
That is, $\liminf_{n} \mu_n^{+}(E)$ is an upper bound for $\{ \mu(A) : A \in \mathfrak{F} \cap E \}$ and $\liminf_{n} \mu_n^{-}(E)$ is an upper bound for $\{ -\mu(A) : A \in \mathfrak{F} \cap E \}$. Then,
$$
\sup\{ \mu(A) : A \in \mathfrak{F} \cap E \} \leq \liminf_{n} \mu_n^{+}(E)
$$
$$
\sup\{ -\mu(A) : A \in \mathfrak{F} \cap E \} \leq \liminf_{n} \mu_n^{-}(E).
$$
Using $\sup\{ -\mu(A) : A \in \mathfrak{F} \cap E \} = -\inf\{ \mu(A) : A \in \mathfrak{F} \cap E \}$, this means that
$$
\mu^{+}(E) \leq \liminf_{n} \mu_n^{+}(E)
$$
$$
\mu^{-}(E) \leq \liminf_{n} \mu_n^{-}(E),
$$
and so $\mu^{\pm}(E) \leq \liminf_{n} \mu_{n}^{\pm}(E)$.

To show $|\mu|(E) \leq \liminf_{n} |\mu_{n}|(E)$ let $E \in \mathfrak{F}$. Hence, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$
|\mu_n|(E) = \sup\bigg\{ \sum_{j=1}^{k} |\mu_n(E_j)| : E_1, \dots, E_k \text{ is a measurable partition of } E \bigg\}.
$$
Thus, let $E_1, \dots, E_k$ be a measurable partition of $E$. It is then clear that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{k} |\mu_n(E_j)| \leq |\mu_n|(E) \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
Since $\mu_n \to \mu$, we get $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{k} |\mu_n(E_j)| = \sum_{j=1}^{k} |\mu(E_j)|$, and so
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{k} |\mu(E_j)| \leq \liminf_{n} |\mu_n|(E).
$$
Given that $E_1, \dots, E_k$ was an arbitrary measurable partition of $E$, it follows that $\liminf_{n} |\mu_n|(E)$ is an upper bound for $\bigg\{ \sum_{j=1}^{m} |\mu(E_j)| : E_1, \dots, E_m \text{ is a measurable partition of } E \bigg\}$, and so
$$
|\mu|(E) = \sup\bigg\{ \sum_{j=1}^{m} |\mu(E_j)| : E_1, \dots, E_m \text{ is a measurable partition of } E \bigg\} \leq \liminf_{n} |\mu_n|(E).
$$